# Rails 3 ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled) in DEV Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, assets, precompiled

I just clone my repo into my server and created a vhost for it.

However I keep getting:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):
```

I already executed `RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

and I'm still getting the same error in the apache2 error.log and when I try to get to my site I just see:

```
We're sorry, but something went wrong.

We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: did you set `config.assets.compile = true` already?

Comment: Try to restart the server after rake assets:precompile and check

Comment: @Vinay where? in the environments/development.rb ?

Comment: Try to restart the server first after you finished the rake assets:precompile and check is that solved and let know

Comment: Now I'm getting  ...espectator.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install` (Bundler::GitError) @Vinay

Comment: Then try to run like `bundle install --deployment`

Comment: wohooo thanksssssssss! @Vinay

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in your config/environments/development.rb file

```
config.assets.manifest = Rails.root.join("public/assets")
```

and restart your server and check.

If your getting espectator.git is not check out.

Then try to run `bundle install`. If it's not solved, try to run `bundle install --deployment`

Comment: Actually, I'm getting the same error ActionView::Template::Error (redesign/four-steps.png isn't precompiled) in other views...

Comment: did you restarted the server?